# How to store keypair generated by RSA is a textfile?

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to write an encryption decryption program using Openssl-RSA. There are only two operations. User stores the data and retrieves it whenever he needs.

To decrypt something, we need the `keypair` that was generated during the encryption. Where and how do I store this `keypair` so that I can access it whenever the user requests decryption of something (which was already encrypted by the user).

Answer (score 1):

Generate keypair with 4096 bit private key and store it to private_key.pem

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem 4096
```

Extract public key from your private key

```
openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem
```

In fact, when you're doing coding, you can have only the private_key.pem, because you can extract the public key manually in the runtime, to encrypt data. Of course provided, that you encrypt this only for yourself, which doesn't make much sense with asymmetric cryptography.